# How to combine these two phrases? size-based and color-based

Tags: grammar, phrases

I want to write:

"We design color-based and size-based models."

Meaning that we design a color-based model and also a size-based model.

Isn't it more appropriate to write:

"We design color/size-based models."?

Comment: Is this sentence to be used in writing up an experiment in which you used one size-based model and one colour-based model? If it is you should use the past tense. Using the present tense makes it sound as though you design these models routinely, perhaps as a business, maybe a bike supplier saying "We design custom cycles for adults and children"

Comment: You can use - "We design both color-based and size-based models" *or* "We design color-based as well as size-based models".

Comment: We design models based on [their] color and size. Although the meaning is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the nouns over the same verb complement (where a noun and a verb participle together function as a compound modifier) when the latter is shared and the noun phrases would be joined by a single conjunction (usually *and* or *or*):

> We design color- and size-based models.

This is equivalent to writing "color-based and size-based models."

Use of the bare dash (no complement) indicates that the reader should be on the lookout for the next "dashed" combination, which will supply the applicable complement.